# SQL: Eliminate duplicate rows that have the same pair of values

Tags: sql, hive

I have this table with 3 fields:

```
ProductA ProductB Count
XX       CC       2
CC       XX       2
ZZ       XX       3
XX       ZZ       3
```

I have to do a sql query, which allows me to delete duplicate rows, ie the row XX CC 2 and CC XX 2 are two duplicate rows because they are the same pair of products.

So the result of the query must be like this:

```
  ProductA ProductB Count
    XX       CC       2
    ZZ       XX       3
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I use Hive 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GREATEST/LEAST` to handle pairs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GREATEST(ProductA, ProductB), LEAST(ProductA, ProductB), cnt
FROM tab
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0be37a33008dca087a07b8c4a0d8a26b)**

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the duplicates are present for every row, as in the sample data.  With this assumption, the SQL is quite simple.  The queries would be a bit more complicated if this assumption is relaxed.

To get the results you want, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where productA < productB;
```

To delete superfluous records, this works for your sample data:

```
delete from t
    where productB > productA;
```

If this is a result set generated by a query, there is probably a simple adjustment to the query that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following answer provided by @lad2025:::

Get the duplicate products:

```
select distinct greatest(producta,productb) p1,least(producta,productb) p2,count from tab3;
```

To delete the duplicate pair of product:

```
delete from tab3
where (producta,productb) 
  not in (select distinct greatest(producta,productb) p1,least(producta,productb) p2 from tab3);
```

Comment: Added delete statement